# Asigning pixel intensities to an unitialized Mat matrix using pointer

Tags: c++, opencv

I try to extract the region of interest (ROI) in a Matrix in OpenCV. It can be easy to do by `cv:Rect`, e.g., `im_roi = im(Rect(x,y, width, height))`. But I prefer to get the data directly from the memory using pointers, which is presumably more efficient. Here below are my codes:

```
Mat im_roi; //the desired matrix holding ROI of im, uninitialized
uchar* im_roi_data = im_roi.data;
uchar* im_data = im.data;

int xstart = x;
int xend = xstart + width;
int ystart = y;
int yend = ystart + height;


for(ii=ystart; ii<yend; ii++)
{
   for(jj=xstart; jj<xend; jj++) //the typo 'jj<xstart' was corrected 
   {
        *im_roi_data++ = *im_data++;
        *im_roi_data++ = *im_data++;
        *im_roi_data++ = *im_data++;
    }
im_data +=3*(im.cols-width);
}
```

The above for-loop codes however do not proceed. I feel the problem may be due to the uninitialized `im_roi`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As Mark Setchell noted it is not the only problem with your code, but yes you must initialize im_roi before accassing its pixels.
2. Using memcpy to copy content of whole row will be much more effecient then copying data pixel by pixel.
3. Writing `im(Rect(x,y, width, height)).copyTo(im_roi);` will be the cleanest AND fastest method of coping ROI (and in that case you don't need to initialize im_roi).

Answer (score 3):

I think your second `for` loop needs to be:

```
for(jj=xstart; jj<xend; jj++)
```